# VB script for send mail adding multiple variable recipients

Tags: email, vbscript, arguments, cc

I am relatively new to writing VB scripts. Essentially, I need to get a functioning VB script to send an email to multiple recipients which vary each email. I need it to have Subject Line, Email Body, Attachment and flexibility to add multiple recipients in the TO, CC and BCC fields without adding individual lines of Add.Recipient for each email address in the TO field. Does anyone have any suggestions or know of any resources to find this information?

I have looked myself and coming up somewhat blank on it.  I have the arguments set in a seperate.txt file. These will vary constantly. I am trying to do this as quickly but efficiently as possible.

I also have not had much luck with the Add.CC command so I took it out for this example...Below is what I currently have written out,

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
arg1 = args.Item(0)  
arg2 = args.Item(1)
arg3 = args.Item(2)
ToAddress = ""&arg1&""
CCAddress = ""&arg2&""
MessageSubject = "Your Order"
MessageBody = "Please find your Order Attached" 
MessageAttachment = ""&arg3&""  
Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.getNamespace("MAPI")
Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody & vbCrLf & MyTime
newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress)
newMail.Attachments.Add(MessageAttachment)
newMail.Send
```

I have the arguments written out as:

```
cscript //nologo test1.vbs email1@email.com email2@email.com y:\folder\test.txt
```

Comment: Man, I wish people who downvoted bothered to give a comment to help the user improve the question.  Anyway, this question is REALLY broad.  You give decent background of what you're trying to accomplish and provide code but fail to describe a specific problem.  What are you specifically stuck on?  There are a wide variety of tutorials on this sort of thing out there (here's one of them: https://youtu.be/Tvbn1HPUSMY) have you checked them out?  Get a handle on exactly what you are having trouble with and ask about that; you'll get much better results.  Good luck!

Comment: The question is quite clear _how to process a list of unknown length_.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Get email addresses, the -2 ignores the attachment
For x = 0 to WScript.Arguments.Count - 2 
    Msgbox Wscript.Arguments(x) & "Count " & x
Next
Msgbox Wscript.Arguments(wscript.arguments.count - 1) & " Attachment"
```

In programming we mostly use procedural steps, as you do. However very frequently we need to do loops. Because we wanted all but the last and then the last I used a `For x =` loop. `For Each` loops are usually better and cleaner code.

This prints out all arguments

```
For each Ag in WScript.Arguments 
    Msgbox Ag 
Next
```